# Cannot write to the response body, the response has completed. Object name: HttpResponseStream

Tags: asp.net-core

I just build sample code for streaming video by ASP.NET Core and I want to support "how to write bytes array to Response.Body"
Please help me!

Here my code!

API

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetVideoContent()
{
     return  new PushStreamResult(OnStreamAvailabe,  "video/mp4", HttpContext.RequestAborted);
 }
```

PushStreamResult

```
//here we re using FileStream to read file from server//  
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, 65536, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
{
    int totalSize = (int)fileStream.Length;
    //here we are saying read bytes from file as long as total size of file 

    //is greater then 0
    while (totalSize > 0)
    {
        int count = totalSize > bufferSize ? bufferSize : totalSize;
        //here we are reading the buffer from orginal file  
        int sizeOfReadedBuffer = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, count);

        //here we are writing the readed buffer to output//
        // ERROR HERE!  
        await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, sizeOfReadedBuffer);

        //and finally after writing to output stream decrementing it to total size of file.  
        totalSize -= sizeOfReadedBuffer;
    }
    //outputStream.Position = 0;
}
```

// ERROR HERE!
**await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, sizeOfReadedBuffer);**

PushStreamResult

```
public class PushStreamResult: IActionResult
{
       private readonly Action<Stream, CancellationToken> _onStreamAvailabe;
       private readonly string _contentType;
       private readonly CancellationToken _requestAborted;

       public PushStreamResult(Action<Stream, CancellationToken> onStreamAvailabe, string contentType, CancellationToken requestAborted)
       {
           _onStreamAvailabe = onStreamAvailabe;
           _contentType = contentType;
           _requestAborted = requestAborted;
       }

       public Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
       {
           var stream = context.HttpContext.Response.Body;
                context.HttpContext.Response.GetTypedHeaders().ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(_contentType);
            _onStreamAvailabe(stream, _requestAborted);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you get an answer to this problem mate?